# Function default object, props with default values are undefined

Tags: javascript

I am working on a function and when I set all of the required inputs as object props and some of them with default values, those that I gave default values to are undefined.

Basically, I want to create some of the properties of the object required and others not.

The issue is that, if I provide a value to `containerClassName` for example, all of the props that have default values become undefined and I can't figure out why?

This will log all default values, no problems

```
beforeAfterComparison()
```

This will log undefined for all of them

```
beforeAfterComparison({ containerClassName: "someClassName" })
```

```js
function beforeAfterComparison(
  {
    containerClassName,
    beforeImageUrl,
    afterImageUrl,
    containerIndex,
    lineWidth,
    lineColor,
    circleDiameter,
    circleColor,
  } = {
    containerIndex: 0,
    lineWidth: 2,
    lineColor: "black",
    circleDiameter: 50,
    circleColor: "lightgray",
  }
) {
  console.log(containerIndex);
  console.log(lineWidth);
  console.log(lineColor);
  console.log(circleDiameter);
  console.log(circleColor);
}

beforeAfterComparison();
console.log("-------------------");
beforeAfterComparison({ containerClassname: "someClassName" });
```

I am expecting that in both cases I should get my default values.

Comment: The issue is that you are giving the _whole object_ a default value, so only if I do `beforeAfterComparison()` or `beforeAfterComparison(undefined)` I'll get all these defaults at once, but if I send a partially filled object I won't get any defaults. You need to set the defaults for each individual object property, and the default for the whole argument just as empty object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the syntax is wrong. Try this,

```
 function beforeAfterComparison(
  {
    containerClassName,
    beforeImageUrl,
    afterImageUrl,
    containerIndex = 0,
    lineWidth = 2,
    lineColor = "black",
    circleDiameter = 50,
    circleColor = "lightgray",
  } = {}) {
  console.log(containerIndex);
  console.log(lineWidth);
  console.log(lineColor);
  console.log(circleDiameter);
  console.log(circleColor);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I dont know why I tried to do it this way:))